# Android Dagger2 Dependency Injection on CustomAdapter

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I learn Dependency Injection using Dagger2 in my android code, I dont have any trouble using it until I try to inject the presenter in my CustomAdapter for ListView, it always return Null Value. The purpose is I want to execute the Presenter function when someone click the ListView Item. This is my CustomAdapter Looks like :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> contactNameList, listGroup;
Context context;
ArrayList<Bitmap> contactImages;
ArrayList<Integer> listContactId;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

@Inject
DetailScreenPresenter detailScreenPresenter;

public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> contactNameList, ArrayList<Bitmap> contactImages, ArrayList<String> listGroup, ArrayList<Integer> listContactId)
{
    this.contactNameList = contactNameList;
    context = mainActivity;
    this.contactImages = contactImages;
    this.listGroup = listGroup;
    this.listContactId = listContactId;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactNameList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class Holder
{

    public Holder(View view,Context context)
    {
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    }

    @BindView(R.id.txtName)
    TextView tvName;

    @BindView(R.id.txtGroup)
    TextView tvGroup;

    @BindView(R.id.imageProfile)
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, null);
    Holder holder=new Holder(rowView, context);

    holder.tvName.setText(contactNameList.get(position));
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(contactImages.get(position));
    holder.tvGroup.setText(listGroup.get(position));
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            detailScreenPresenter.loadDetail(listContactId.get(position));
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
}
```

and this is the MainActivity that trigger the CustomAdapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainScreenContact.View {

@BindView(R.id.listContact)
ListView listView;

ArrayList<String> listName;
ArrayList<Bitmap> listImage;
ArrayList<String> listGroup;
ArrayList<Integer> listContactId;
HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> tempImageArray;
String[] letter={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};


@Inject
MainScreenPresenter mainPresenter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    listName = new ArrayList<>();
    listImage = new ArrayList<>();
    tempImageArray = new HashMap<>();
    listGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    listContactId = new ArrayList<>();

    DaggerMainScreenComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(((App) getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .mainScreenModule(new MainScreenModule(this, new ContactDatabaseHelper(this)))
            .build().inject(this);

    mainPresenter.loadPost();
}


@Override
public void showPosts(List<Post> posts) {

    Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Post post1, Post post2) {
            String name1=post1.getFirstName()+" "+post1.getLastName();
            String name2=post2.getFirstName()+" "+post2.getLastName();
            return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
        }
    });

    int indexGroup=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {

        if(posts.get(i).getProfilePic().contains("http"))
            mainPresenter.loadImage(posts.get(i).getProfilePic(), i);
        else
            mainPresenter.loadImage("http://example.com", i);


        if(Arrays.binarySearch(letter,Character.toString(posts.get(i).getFirstName().charAt(0)).toUpperCase())==-1)
        {
            if(listGroup.size()==0)
                listGroup.add("*");
            else
                listGroup.add(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            if(!listGroup.get(indexGroup).equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(posts.get(i).getFirstName().charAt(0)))) {
                listGroup.add(Character.toString(posts.get(i).getFirstName().charAt(0)).toUpperCase());
                indexGroup = i;
            }
            else
                listGroup.add(" ");
        }

        listContactId.add(i, posts.get(i).getId());
        listName.add(i, posts.get(i).getFirstName() + " " + posts.get(i).getLastName());

    }

}


@Override
public void showError(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void showComplete() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void setImageProfile(Bitmap profileBmp, int x) {
    tempImageArray.put(x, profileBmp);

    if(tempImageArray.size()==listName.size())
    {

        SortedSet<Integer> keys = new TreeSet<Integer>(tempImageArray.keySet());
        for(Integer key : keys)
        {
            listImage.add(tempImageArray.get(key));
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, listName, listImage, listGroup, listContactId));
    }

}
}
```

Please help how to inject the DetailScreenPresenter presenter.

Thanks alot

Comment: You have to call `component.inject(this);` in adapter constructor

Comment: To add to the two answers. You need something like this:     DaggerMainScreenComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(((App) getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .mainScreenModule(new MainScreenModule(this, new ContactDatabaseHelper(this)))
            .build().inject(this); inside the constructor of your adapter.

Answer (score 3):

In general, in order to perform injection into any Object, you should explicitly call `<some_dagger_component>.inject(<target_object>)`.

In your case, you could do it this way:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, listName, listImage, listGroup, listContactId);

DaggerMainScreenComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(((App) getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .mainScreenModule(new MainScreenModule(this, new ContactDatabaseHelper(this)))
            .build().inject(adapter);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, what you're trying to do is an abuse of dependency injection framework - you should not perform injection into adapter, but simply pass the required objects to adapter's constructor.

In [this post](http://www.techyourchance.com/dependency-injection-android/) you can find additional information about dependency injection in Android.

Comment: Thank you. I was also trying to somehow make this work and your comment "is an abuse of ..." brought me to the point to reevaluate my decision and simply pass the needed var.